# How to create a radius in google map and check if marker being fetched from the database is inside circle (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to know how to create a radius in my current location with a range of 800 meters. And also how can I check if the marker that I fetched from the database is inside my circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code snippet on how to add radius on stackoverflow.

```
//radius in meters
    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).radius(800).strokeColor(Color.RED));
    circle.setVisible(true);
```

And to my question on how to check if marker being fetched from the database is within the radius, I use

> Location.distanceBetween()[Google Maps | Calculate Distance Between 2 Locations (Android Tutorials)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9V0p_2lVoJo)

And then I added an if statement

```
if (result[0] >= 450 && result[0] <= 800) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "distance: "+ result[0] + "\nBus is inside radius", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For task like this I have a static helper class. Here is the code I use to create the circle:

```
public static CircleOptions setMapCircleMeters(LatLng latLng, float meters){
    CircleOptions options = null;
    try {
        options = new CircleOptions();

        options.center(latLng);
        options.radius(meters);
        options.fillColor(Color.argb(70, 80, 80, 80));
        options.strokeWidth(2.0f);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "  CircleOptions --- " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return options;
}
```

You can easily change the attributes of the `fillColor` or `strokeWidth` to suit your needs.

Now, to find out if a location is within the distance you wish to check:

```
public static boolean isInRangeMeters(LatLng pt1, LatLng pt2, double meters){
    boolean inRange = false;
    try{
        double distance = getDistanceMeters(pt1, pt2);

        inRange = (distance <= meters);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return inRange;
}

public static double getDistanceMeters(LatLng pt1, LatLng pt2){
    double distance = 0d;
    try{
        double theta = pt1.longitude - pt2.longitude;
        double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pt1.latitude)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pt2.latitude))
                    + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pt1.latitude)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pt2.latitude)) 
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));

        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = Math.toDegrees(dist);
        distance = dist * 60 * 1853.1596;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return distance;
}
```